# Excel Formula to copy cell value to a column based on condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to reformat my spreadsheet. Here's a small model of it:

```
[  ][;9][10][  ]
[  ][  ][X1][Y1]
[  ][  ][X2][Y2]
[  ][;9][20][  ]
[  ][  ][X3][Y3]
[  ][  ][X4][Y4]
[  ][  ][X5][Y5]
[  ][;9][43][  ]
[  ][  ][X6][Y7]
```

How can I reformat it to look like this:

```
[  ][;9][10][  ]
[10][  ][X ][Y ]
[10][  ][X2][Y2]
[  ][;9][20][  ]
[20][  ][X3][Y3]
[20][  ][X4][Y4]
[20][  ][X5][Y5]
[  ][;9][43][  ]
[43][  ][X6][Y7]
```

I was looking to use the if statement, but I'm not sure how to do two things:
1) include the empty cell before the ;9
2) update the value in the left most cell every time the value after the ;9 updates (it should include this value instead)

UPDATE: So I've been trying the answers, but it gives me an error. It turns out I have an extra line in my spreadsheet I didn't notice before.

[image]

So I'm trying this and it's close to working. However, I'm actually looking for it to change dynamically if C1 changes number.

This works at the beginning:
[image]

But not after the value changes. Here, it should have the value 22584:

[image]

This doesn't work either:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is more reliable (for cases when X and Y are numbers).

In A1: `=IF(ISBLANK(B1),LOOKUP(";9",$B$1:B1,$C$1:C1),"")` and fill down.

Comment: I tried your formula @MaxZelensky, but it gives me a error as well. I may be the way my spreadsheet is formatted.

Answer (score 2):

With the top `;9` in B1, put this into A1,

```
 =IF(ISBLANK(B1), LOOKUP(1E+99, C$1:C1), "")
```

Then fill down as necessary.

[image: Lookup 1E99]

Your revised question might be better answered with the following in A1,

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1), INDEX(C$1:C1, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW($1:1)/(B$1:B1=";9"), 1)), "")
```

Comment: I tried your formula @Jeeped, but it gives me an error. Any ideas?

Comment: It is considered bad form to change the conditions of your question to the point that answers that *were* correct are no longer correct. It is especially bad form to do so without acknowledging the (formerly) correct answer(s). In short, it is hard to hit a moving target.

Comment: sorry about that--I did not initially see that the form of my spreadsheet was a little different. Would you consider it better form if a new question be opened?